# javax.transaction.RollbackException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have been occuring below exception while committing transaction.
I am getting transaction on javax.ejb.SessionContext

```
Error Code: EJB_ERROR
Title: EJB Error
Message: An unexpected EJB error occurred.  This is mostly triggered when a CMP bean fails a persistance operation, which should be very rare.
Severity: 3
Additional Message: Transaction commit failed due to the enclosed exception.
Error Location: DealerDataLoaderBean.commit

Original Exception Error Stack: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1221)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:991)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:913)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper.commit(UserTransactionWrapper.java:305)
    at com.freightliner.dps.dealer.DealerDataLoaderBean.commit(DealerDataLoaderBean.java:1044)
    at com.freightliner.dps.dealer.DealerDataLoaderBean.load(DealerDataLoaderBean.java:142)
    at com.freightliner.dps.dealer.EJSRemoteStatelessDealerDataLoader_66b9401b.load(EJSRemoteStatelessDealerDataLoader_66b9401b.java:27)
    at com.freightliner.dps.dealer._DealerDataLoader_Stub.load(_DealerDataLoader_Stub.java:264)
    at com.freightliner.dps.admin.ToolsAction.dealerUpdate(ToolsAction.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.freightliner.membershipservices.webmethods.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.tran.SyncDriver.beforeCompletion(SyncDriver.java:310)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2312)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:533)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:978)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerTx.beforeCompletion(ContainerTx.java:867)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.tran.SyncDriver.beforeCompletion(SyncDriver.java:280)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.WsEJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR6022E: Error using adapter to create or execute an Interaction. com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.cci.WSInteractionImpl@59b259b2
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.ConcreteBeanStatefulInstanceExtensionImpl.executeStore(ConcreteBeanStatefulInstanceExtensionImpl.java:2131)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.CBReadyState.ejbStore(CBReadyState.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.ConcreteBeanStatefulInstanceExtensionImpl.ejbStore(ConcreteBeanStatefulInstanceExtensionImpl.java:604)
    at com.freightliner.dps.dealer.ConcreteDealerDetails_8f424d45.ejbStore(ConcreteDealerDetails_8f424d45.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerManaged2_0BeanO.store(ContainerManaged2_0BeanO.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EntityBeanO.beforeCompletion(EntityBeanO.java:1236)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerTx.beforeCompletion(ContainerTx.java:611)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR6022E: Error using adapter to create or execute an Interaction. com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.cci.WSInteractionImpl@59b259b2
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.dataaccess.DataAccessRequestImpl.execute(DataAccessRequestImpl.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.ConcreteBeanStatefulInstanceExtensionImpl.executeStore(ConcreteBeanStatefulInstanceExtensionImpl.java:2108)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C90088, DRIVER=3.59.81DSRA0010E: SQL State = 57033, Error Code = -913
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:679)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bn.b(bn.java:2231)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bn.c(bn.java:2214)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.k(cb.java:355)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:61)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better have a look at your DB2. According to the stacktrace you have a deadlock there; So check the sequence of statements you execute to see why a deadlock occurred.

[Check this out!](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.codes/n913.htm)

Comment: Did u find the reason of the deadlock?